# Why can't I have same struct type property in struct in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a `struct` type called Node like below:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node next; 
}
```

I get compile time error when I compile above code but If I make it a class everything is fine.

```
class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next; 
    }
```

What is the difference between two ( I know one is `struct ( value type )` and one is `class(ref type )` ) ?

Comment: Because you would blow the stack.

Comment: How much do you understand about the difference between value types and reference types? What would you expect the *size* of your `Node` struct to be? (Given that it has to contain another `Node` struct and an `int`...)

Comment: Your struct size would sum to infinity... and beyond!

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I know it now why the compiler complain about cyclic nesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you ever programmed in C-class language? You know, classes/structures and pointers and such?

If you had so, then remember: in C# "classes" are passed "as pointers", while "structs" are passed in they raw binary form, they are copied around just like anything non-pointerish non-referencish in C/C++. All other restrictions for nesting are preserved, just named differently.

In C# you can have a 'class X' containing a field of type 'class X' because "classes" are never placed anywhere directly. Such field is actually a 4/8 byte pointer/reference. The size of 'class X' is easily determinable. In contrast, in C# you cannot have a 'struct X' that contains a field of type 'struct X'. Such field would be embeded in the outer struct directly, not by pointer/reference. What would be the size of the 'struct X' if it contained another 'struct X' which surely by its definition would contain another 'struct X' that would contain .... where would be the end? How would you mark the end? How the compiler/runtime would know how much space to allocate when you write "new X()" ? Just as in C/C++ you cannot create recursively nested types directly (you can do that only by pointers/references), here in C# you cannot create recursive structs.

Comment: If your eyes sore because of the imperfect description of inner mechanisms of C#/CLR/etc, well, try flushing them with some cold water :) It was 100% intended not to be perfect, but rather be quickly understandable for C/C++ coder, who often find problems in C# due to a similar but different terminology in this environment.

Answer (score 3):

If you define `class`, `Node` is just reference to reference type `Node`. In strucure case you have nesting of `Node` stuct i.e. cyclic nesting Node in Node.